# How to build yocto distribution from locally stored sourcecode, without internet access

Tags: docker, yocto

I'm building a custom Linux distribution for an embedded target. I want to be able to build exactly the same image again 20 years in the future and I want to build without internet access. Thus, I need to store all the downloaded sourcecode.

How can I achieve that? Is it enough to build on some host with internet access and then store the resulting build/downloads directory?

I guess I also need to store the build host (e.g. store or be able to re-create the docker container). Maybe the most practical way is to store the contents of the docker image after building? Perhaps just excluding e.g. everything under build/tmp and build/cache?

Comment: Note, after the build you can set `BB_NO_NETWORK = "1"` in `local.conf` to stop it trying to access the internet again. If you clean out something then try building again with this flag you should aim for no errors.

Comment: Check BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS too., to archive e.g git repos.  I'm wondering what Docker will give within 20 years?